# How to start clamav-freshclam.service properly : freshclam: ... Can't save PID to file /var/run/clamav/freshclam.pid: No such file or directory

Tags: 20.04, systemd, clamav

the service clamav-freshclam.service cannot be started :

```bash
$ sudo systemctl start clamav-freshclam.service 
$ systemctl status clamav-freshclam.service 
● clamav-freshclam.service - ClamAV virus database updater
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/clamav-freshclam.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-08-21 15:21:43 CEST; 8s ago
       Docs: man:freshclam(1)
             man:freshclam.conf(5)
             https://docs.clamav.net/
    Process: 103714 ExecStart=/usr/bin/freshclam -d --foreground=true (code=exited, status=2)
   Main PID: 103714 (code=exited, status=2)

Aug 21 15:21:43 seb-C70D-B-311 systemd[1]: Started ClamAV virus database updater.
Aug 21 15:21:43 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[103714]: Sun Aug 21 15:21:43 2022 -> !Cant save PID to file /var/run/clamav/freshclam.pid: No such file or directory
Aug 21 15:21:43 seb-C70D-B-311 systemd[1]: clamav-freshclam.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Aug 21 15:21:43 seb-C70D-B-311 systemd[1]: clamav-freshclam.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
$ echo $?
3
$ grep PidFile /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf
PidFile /var/run/clamav/freshclam.pid
$ ls /var/run/clamav/
ls: cannot access '/var/run/clamav/': No such file or directory
```

My guess is that the `/var/run/clamav/` direcory is not automatically created.

EDIT0 : Found it :

```bash
$ grep -A1 Automatically /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf
# Automatically created by the clamav-freshclam postinst
# Comments will get lost when you reconfigure the clamav-freshclam package
```

It seems I need to reconfigure the `clamav-freshclam` package :

```bash
$ sudo mv /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf /etc/clamav/freshclam.BACK
renamed '/etc/clamav/freshclam.conf' -> '/etc/clamav/freshclam.BACK'
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure clamav-freshclam
$ sdiff -s /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf /etc/clamav/freshclam.BACK
ReceiveTimeout 0                       |    ReceiveTimeout 30
NotifyClamd /etc/clamav/clamd.conf             <
DatabaseMirror db.fr.clamav.net                |    DatabaseMirror db.local.clamav.net
                               >    PidFile /var/run/clamav/freshclam.pid
$ sudo systemctl start clamav-freshclam.service
$ systemctl status clamav-freshclam.service  
● clamav-freshclam.service - ClamAV virus database updater
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/clamav-freshclam.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-08-21 17:29:22 CEST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:freshclam(1)
             man:freshclam.conf(5)
             https://docs.clamav.net/
   Main PID: 63346 (freshclam)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8130)
     Memory: 233.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/clamav-freshclam.service
             └─63346 /usr/bin/freshclam -d --foreground=true

Aug 21 17:30:31 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[63346]: Sun Aug 21 17:30:31 2022 -> main.cvd updated (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, f-level: 90, builder: sigmgr)
Aug 21 17:30:31 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[63346]: Sun Aug 21 17:30:31 2022 -> bytecode database available for download (remote version: 333)
Aug 21 17:30:31 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[63346]: Sun Aug 21 17:30:31 2022 -> Testing database: /var/lib/clamav/tmp.0bd40b5775/clamav-afbed25073ea69c84c5b4b>
Aug 21 17:30:31 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[63346]: Sun Aug 21 17:30:31 2022 -> Database test passed.
Aug 21 17:30:31 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[63346]: Sun Aug 21 17:30:31 2022 -> bytecode.cvd updated (version: 333, sigs: 92, f-level: 63, builder: awillia2)
Aug 21 17:30:31 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[63346]: WARNING: Ignoring deprecated option AllowSupplementaryGroups at /etc/clamav/clamd.conf:11
Aug 21 17:30:31 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[63346]: WARNING: Ignoring deprecated option DetectBrokenExecutables at /etc/clamav/clamd.conf:41
Aug 21 17:30:31 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[63346]: WARNING: Ignoring deprecated option ScanOnAccess at /etc/clamav/clamd.conf:61
Aug 21 17:30:31 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[63346]: ERROR: Parse error at /etc/clamav/clamd.conf:78: Unknown option StatsEnabled
Aug 21 17:30:31 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[63346]: Sun Aug 21 17:30:31 2022 -> !NotifyClamd: Cant find or parse configuration file /etc/clamav/clamd.conf
$ grep -A1 Automatically /etc/clamav/clamd.conf 
#Automatically Generated by clamav-base postinst
#To reconfigure clamd run #dpkg-reconfigure clamav-base
```

It seems I also need to reconfigure the `clamav-base` package :

```bash
$ sudo mv /etc/clamav/clamd.conf /etc/clamav/clamd.BACK
renamed '/etc/clamav/clamd.conf' -> '/etc/clamav/clamd.BACK'
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure clamav-base
$ ls /etc/clamav/clamd.conf
ls: cannot access '/etc/clamav/clamd.conf': No such file or directory
$ sudo systemctl restart clamav-freshclam.service 
$ systemctl status clamav-freshclam.service  
● clamav-freshclam.service - ClamAV virus database updater
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/clamav-freshclam.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-08-21 17:40:30 CEST; 11s ago
       Docs: man:freshclam(1)
             man:freshclam.conf(5)
             https://docs.clamav.net/
   Main PID: 65732 (freshclam)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8130)
     Memory: 3.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/clamav-freshclam.service
             └─65732 /usr/bin/freshclam -d --foreground=true

Aug 21 17:40:30 seb-C70D-B-311 systemd[1]: Started ClamAV virus database updater.
Aug 21 17:40:30 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[65732]: Sun Aug 21 17:40:30 2022 -> ClamAV update process started at Sun Aug 21 17:40:30 2022
Aug 21 17:40:30 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[65732]: Sun Aug 21 17:40:30 2022 -> ^Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
Aug 21 17:40:30 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[65732]: Sun Aug 21 17:40:30 2022 -> ^Local version: 0.103.6 Recommended version: 0.103.7
Aug 21 17:40:30 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[65732]: Sun Aug 21 17:40:30 2022 -> DONT PANIC Read https://docs.clamav.net/manual/Installing.html
Aug 21 17:40:30 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[65732]: Sun Aug 21 17:40:30 2022 -> daily.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 26634, sigs: 1998006, f-level: 90, b>
Aug 21 17:40:30 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[65732]: Sun Aug 21 17:40:30 2022 -> main.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, f-level: 90, build>
Aug 21 17:40:30 seb-C70D-B-311 freshclam[65732]: Sun Aug 21 17:40:30 2022 -> bytecode.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 333, sigs: 92, f-level: 63, build>
```

Problem solved, now I need to update it :-).

For me : [ClamAV installation](https://docs.clamav.net/manual/Installing.html) and [ClamAV configuration](https://docs.clamav.net/manual/Usage/Configuration.html)

Comment: did you add this `PidFile /var/run/clamav/freshclam.pid` yourself? If so "How can I have the /var/run/clamav/ direcory automatically created ?" You can not; you need to do that yourself. Well you could add a `mkdir -p  /var/run/clamav/` to your service :)

Comment: @Rinzwind No, I didn't add this `PidFile /var/run/clamav/freshclam.pid` line.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. 1 warning though: clamav is for scanning attachments added to mail for -windows-. It has an upper limit for files and will not scan files above that. It will do nothing on Linux except falsely report problems. Pratically useless and a waste of your sysyems power if all you use is Linux ;) If this is a production server holding sensitive data scanning for -rootkits- is far more important

Comment: @Rinzwind Yeah, at home I only use an Ubuntu desktop. `systemctl -a list-unit-files clam*` only returns the `clamav-freshclam.service` so it seems it does no scan at all but only updates the databases every hour because `grep Checks /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf` returns `Checks 24`. If I want automatic scans, I guess I need to configure it.

Comment: @Rinzwind At work, the security guy asked me to install an antivirus on the Linux servers. I read you suggest -rootkits- scanners. Can you tell me more ?

Comment: "At work, the security guy asked me to install an antivirus on the Linux servers." if this is to scan windows files to then send them to windows that will work. otherwise ask "why?"  as long as you use the official repo's not virus will arrive on your system. Rootkits: https://linuxsecurity.com/features/what-you-need-to-know-about-linux-rootkit Those abuse bugs in software. If you have servers that allow people in you need to evaluate the services used for that and update CVEs